# VSTO 2010 Outlook add-in shows error message while installing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook, vsto, office-2007

I have a VSTO 2010 Office 2007 Outlook Add-In deployed from Click-Once. It works on my dev machine and on a standard user machine and fails on another. On the first time it was installed but the add-in didn't appear in Outlook. Then I removed that Add-In in the control panel and deleted the "outcmd.dat" file. When I'm trying to install a new plugin, it shows an error message:

> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.AddInAlreadyInstalledException: The customization cannot be installed because another version is currently installed and cannot be upgraded from this location. To install this version of the customization, first use Add or Remove Programs to uninstall this program: WG plugin. Then install the new customization from the following location: file:///C:/WG25.10.2012/WG plugin-php.vsto
>   
>    at 
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.VerifySolutionCodebaseIsUnchanged(Uri uri, String subscriptionId, Boolean previouslyInstalled)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn() "

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/d7d57446-f0b2-4b9e-96b8-966218306ddd/

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin

Mage.exe -cc

Comment: I had the same problem, and I found this article helped me fix it:
[Installing Office Customization][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544210/installing-office-customization

Answer (score 0):

try this link , you have a command to run in this page,just run it the problem will be fixed. command: "rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache"

or try this link

[How do I completely uninstall a ClickOnce application from my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896223/completely-uninstall-a-clickonce-application-from-my-computer)