# VSTO. How to determine the project GUID?

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in, office-addins, ms-project

I am trying to create an add-in.
I get an error.
I found a solution to the error - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4351185/10530657).
To solve the error, the string `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTA\Solutions\{GUID}` is required.

**Question:** where can I get `{GUID}`?

[image]

---

### Update-1

[image]

---

### Updated-2

[image]

---

### Updated-3

I seem to have found my add-on.
In my case, {GUID} = `b037194d-afa5-4109-a7dd-36fbdd2d1610`?
The address will look like this - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTA\Solutions\b037194d-afa5-4109-a7dd-36fbdd2d1610`?

[image]

Comment: Did you try looking in that path (or similar path) for the GUID? The Name of key will be the path to the .vsto file, and the Value of the key will be the GUID.

Comment: @RachelHettinger See Update-1.
Sorry, I can’t understand you.
  Could you try to formulate your decision differently.

Comment: @RachelHettinger Do you mean to go to all the folders that are in the `Solutions` folder?
And if there are files, then find files that will be related to my add-in?

Comment: @RachelHettinger see `Update - 2`.
Did I understand you correctly that I need to find my add-in in the way that I indicated in the picture?
Then why is it necessary to do this at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTO\SolutionMetadata\` , and not at  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTA\Solutions\{GUID}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are publishing your addin using **ClickOnce** deployment in the options there is field called '**Product Name**' which is added to the registry of your addin as 'String value'.

[image]

Here is the entry in the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTA\Solutions)

[image]

In our deployment process we needed a post deployment action to set the icon of the application and the only way to find the **GUID** was registry seek in the **Solution** sub-path for entry with specific '**Product Name**' - this is in case you need some automation.

Comment: see `Update-3`. I seem to have found my add-on.  
In my case, {GUID} = `b037194d-afa5-4109-a7dd-36fbdd2d1610`?  
The address will look like this - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTA\Solutions\b037194d-afa5-4109-a7dd-36fbdd2d1610`?

Comment: @eusataf Yes, this is the registry key you need to remove. After you remove it, the office app (Word, Excel .. etc) will not try to load it.